# Want to use TriggerDagRunOperator in Airflow to trigger many sub-dags by using only Main-dag with bashoperator(sub-dag operator)

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

Unable to understand the concept of Payload in airflow with TriggerDagRunOperator.Please help me to understand this term in a very easy way.

Answer (score 0):

the `TriggerDagRunOperator` triggers a DAG run for a specified `dag_id`. This needs a `trigger_dag_id` with type `string` and a python_callable param which is a reference to a python function that will be called while passing it the `context` object and a placeholder object `obj` for your callable to fill and return if you want a DagRun created. This `obj` object contains a `run_id` and **`payload`** attribute that you can modify in your function.

The `run_id` should be a unique identifier for that DAG run, and the **payload** has to be a **picklable** object that will be made available to your tasks while executing that DAG run. Your function header should look like `def foo(context, dag_run_obj):`

**picklable** simply means it can be serialized by the [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) module.  For a basic understanding of this, see [what can be pickled and unpickled?](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled). The [pickle protocol](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#the-pickle-protocol) provides more details, and shows how classes can customize the process.

Reference: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/d313d8d24b1969be9154b555dd91466a2489e1c7/airflow/operators/dagrun_operator.py#L37

Comment: If i talk about Controller_dag which is controlling(triggering) rest of target_dags and in Controller_dag . After triggering target_dags, Controller_dags is showing green marks for its all tasks but if i will look on target dags which are still in running status. Means Controller dags doesn't have any dependency on target dags tasks either it is completed or not.
I want something which can help me to set Controller Dag dependency over target dag tasks. If any task is failing in target dag then in Controller dag status is showing as failed.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, i was also struggling setting a dynamic payload:

```
num_runs = 3
runs = [str(uuid.uuid4()) for _ in range(num_runs)]

run_dags = TriggerDagRunOperator.partial(
    task_id='test_07_few_opt_ins_triggered_dag',
    trigger_dag_id='test_07_few_opt_ins_triggered_dag',
).expand(
    trigger_run_id=runs,
    conf=[{"line": "1"}, {"line": "2"}, {"line": "3"}]
)
```

Above we have 3 runs, and we need to set the `expand` filling the conf with the same number of "runs".

Then, in the triggered DAG:

```
@task
def start(dag_run=None):
    print(f"consuming line {dag_run.conf.get('line')}")

start()
```